# Register new user with laravel as an API

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, authentication, redirect

I am building an Angular app which relies on a separate Laravel API, and am trying to register a new user.

Out of the box, Laravel 5.1 [Authentication](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication) provides a number of handy methods to register a user, but they are suited for using Laravel for the entire app, meaning `blade template` frontend.

I added this to my routes.php file:

```
$router->controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController'
]);
```

The route `/auth/register` is provided for me, so I tried creating a new user:

From DHC:

> We are sorry, but Chrome API does not allow to get a response body for
>   redirect.

From my App:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dde.localhost/auth/register. The
>   request was redirected to 'http://dde.localhost/home', which is
>   disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

I found the reason for this is because of the method `/auth/register` calls: `postRegister()` in `RegistersUsers.php`:

`App\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController@postRegister`

Which looks like:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    Auth::login($this->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

This has a redirect which I guess would normally redirect to a blade Welcome template or something.

If I comment out the redirect, and simply return a `200 response`,

```
 return Response::make('user created', 200);
```

I get a CORS error:

> http://dde.localhost/auth/register. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

This is odd, because I am routing all routes through BarryCORS middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function(\Illuminate\Routing\Router $router) {
```

Which says `*` origins are allowed.

**So the question is: How can I set up registration and auth for a frontend app that only uses Laravel for an API**

---

There seems to be two calls made to `register` for each single call from my frontend application:

**First**: Seems like the first request has the access control headers and it's an OPTIONS http request:

```
Request URL:http://dde.localhost/auth/register
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
//Response Headers: 
access-control-allow-headers:ACCEPT, CONTENT-TYPE
access-control-allow-methods:GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
access-control-allow-origin:http://localhost:1337
Allow:GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE
```

**Second**: and in the second, the POST is finally called, and with the payload, but the access control headers are stripped

```
Request URL:http://dde.localhost/auth/register
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

//Response Headers: there are no access-control-allow methods attached
//Payload
{username: "testname", password: "some random password"}
```

Why is this?

Comment: Did you check if the response actually has those headers?

Comment: Better go with a token based auth.

Comment: @fos.alex see above edit plz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OPTIONS request before a CORS call is standard, it is precisely to check the server's response headers.

If you are getting a HTTP 500 it is because there is something wrong with the server. If it were for CORS alone you would get some 40x error.
Check your laravel app logs, something is breaking server-side.